# Find Value of a Cell- Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to find value of Cell "B2" in Google AppScript so I can do something with it later. My code is not logging anything for this value. Any tips?

```
 //Get Customer Name from Sheet
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var cusRange = ss.getRange("B2:B2");
      var cusName = cusRange.getDisplayValue();
      Logger.log(cusName);
```

I've tried multiple modifications but cannot achieve my desired results.

Comment: Try this `var cusName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue();`

Comment: Same result- no value shown on log.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: How are you viewing your logs?

Comment: view-->logs. Looking at the Spreadsheet there is a value in cell B2. But I am doing a copy/paste right before I run the code to pull the value. Wondering if I'm pulling the value before I paste the data.

Comment: The log shows as follows: `[17-05-10 23:43:41:187 EDT] Logger.log([, []]) [0 seconds]` This was pulled from the Execution Transcript.

Comment: My log shows as follows: `[17-05-10 20:29:18:430 PDT] No Names`  and the string in B2 is No Names.

Comment: Maybe I need to convert the data to a string and then read it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code like this and it works fine.  I replaced ss with sheet in the third line. It worked for me.

```
function test()
{
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var cusRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B2");//replaced ss with sheet
      var cusName = cusRange.getDisplayValue();
      Logger.log(cusName);

}
```

I think you may have been viewing the execution transcript.  Try logs instead.  The selection right below it on the View Tab.

Comment: This works-- thanks for the help. There must be something with my original script. I created a secondary script just for this task and it works with no problem.